# XPages Extension library DOJO Tab container control CSS Modifications

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-extlib

I want to know, Is there any way to change the Style sheets of the ***extension library DOJO Tab container control***?

Thanks & regards,

Yogesh Kashid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to change the Style sheets of the extension library DOJO Tab container control is to create and use an own css resource. This way you can change every single table part's look and it would be valid for all DOJO Tab container controls in your application.

1. Create under Resources\Style Sheet a my.css file
2. Add the Style changes for DOJO Tab classes in my.css file. The style classes start with "dijitTab..." and you can find them analyzing the rendered page in browser. 
   [image]
   For changing the tab labels to red you would write e.g.

> ```
> .dijitTabContainerTopNone {
>   color: red;
> }
> ```

3 . Add the my.css class to your theme

> ```
> <theme extends="oneuiv2.1">
>   <resource>
>       <content-type>text/css</content-type>
>       <href>my.css</href>
>   </resource>
> </theme>
> ```